# Error: Object(char message []) not compiling with Object("Text")

Tags: c++

I am having an issue with trying to send a `("msg")` from main to a Object`(char arr[])`.

```
InputNum(char msg []) 
{ 
    cout << msg; 
    cin >> _num;
}
```

```
int main()
{ 
    InputNum num ("Enter a Number"); 
}
```

The above throws an error from the g++ compiler:

> ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]

So, I am sending a String in main to a char[ ] parameter. But I'm not sure *why* that is a problem. I was under the illusion that a char[ ] IS a String, which <strike>I guess is incorrect</strike> is incorrect. Any general advice on what and how to fix it, I would appreciate greatly.

Also, code is inspired by p.44 "C++ In Action" by Bartosz Milewski (2001).

Editted: greatly :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying (unknowingly) to make a string literal writable. C++ doesnt like this at all.

You have to do

```
void InputNum(const char msg []) {
   cout << msg;
}
```

this promises the compiler that you wont try to change the conents of 'msg'

Comment: Success! Thank you @pm100 . That seems to solve all of my problems.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Don't use this.

Comment: @AnoopRana It solves my issue under the conditions I provided, correctly.

Comment: @ConorFair So does my answer as well. We can't guess what you actually want. We can only answer based on you current/original quesiton. And since in your original question there is no mentioned of the fact that you want to declare InputNum as an object. So how would we know of that? We can only answer based on your original quesion. And, this answer is clearly wrong according to your original question.

Comment: @AnoopRana You're right my original wording is vague. I could have referred to a "constructor" instead of a "function" to clarify or perhaps provide 20 lines of code instead of 2. I am a noob with a bug that got solved.

Comment: @ConorFair It doesn't matter whether you're a beginner or not. A wrong answer is wrong, period. If you have marked this answer as correct because it solves a problem that doesn't even exist in your original question example, then IMO it is not right. If someone in the future copy-paste the solution given in this answer to you original question, then he/she will get error. Meaning this answer doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @AnoopRana can you explain to me whats wrong with it, I see that I omitted the return type  -its on the previous line - some people like that style from way back - (wink wink )

Comment: @pm100 You didn't speify the return type of the function `InputNum` while defining it. Which previous line are you talking about? I don't see a return type in your answer.

Comment: @AnoopRana I was kidding. A common (old) style was to put the return type on the previous line and have the function name start in column 1 of the next. I am jokingly giving myslef an excuse for missin it out (that why I had wink wink)

Comment: @pm100 Oh, i missed the humour/joke, lol.

Comment: @AnoopRana and if the OP had done that then my solution would be correct, anyway I have fixed it now.

Comment: @pm100 It is our responsibility to give/provide technically correct answer. Now your answer is ok.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your given code.

##### Mistake 1

The type of the parameter `msg` in you function `InputNum` is actually a `char*` i.e., a *pointer to `char`*. This is because `char[]` decays to `char*` in case of pass by value. Meanwhile `"Enter a Number"` is a **string literal** of type `const char[15]` which decays to `const char*`. Thus, you're essentially passing a `const char*` as an argument where the parameter is of type `char*`. That is, there is mismatch in type of argument passed and the parameter `msg`.

To **solve** this you should add a **low-level const** to the parameter `msg` as shown below:

```
//-------vvvvv--------------->note the const added here
InputNum(const char msg []) 
{ 
    cout << msg; 
}
```

##### Mistake 2

You've not specified the return type of the function `InputNum`. To **solve** this you should add `void` as the return type as shown below:

```
//vvvv-------------------------------> note void added as return type here
  void InputNum(const char msg []) { 
      cout << msg; 
  }
```

##### Mistake 3

You should remove `num` from the statement `InputNum num ("Enter a Number");` as shown below:

```
//------v------------------->num removed from here
InputNum ("Enter a Number");
```

##### Solution 1

Here is the complete modified solution incorporating all the above 2 solutions.

```
void InputNum(const char msg []) 
{ 
    std::cout << msg;
}
int main() 
{
    InputNum ("Enter a Number");
    
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/hHUyO5T7w)

##### Solution 2

You can also use `std::string` as shown below:

```
void InputNum(const std::string& msg) 
{ 
    std::cout << msg;
}
int main() 
{
    InputNum ("Enter a Number");
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/uBA9eVsRk)

Comment: For the snippet shown you are generally correct I should make a void function, but, I want to declare InputNum as an object so that I can store a variable with `cin` and practice some object-oriented design stuff. I just got bogged down with a bug (If I'm understanding this right...) going from  `const char[]` to `char*`. Thank you for the clarification on those terms though.

Comment: @ConorFair You're welcome. We can't guess what you actually want. We can only answer based on you current/original quesiton. And since in your original question there is no mentioned of the fact that you want to declare InputNum as an object. So how would we know of that? We can only answer based on your original quesion. And, currently accepted answer is clearly wrong given your original question.

Comment: @ConorFair Also it wastes people's time. I spent `10-12` minutes writing/formatting my answer. And then you accepted a wrong answer. Moreover in that answer the phrase *"C++ doesn't like this at all"* does not answer anything. Neither the user tells what is actually happening(which is decaying).